# Передать дата-атрибут в поле input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть кнопка, по которой вызывается всплывающее окно с формой заявки

```
<a  data-product="Шкаф" class="button product_type_variable add_to_cart_button" href="#standard-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal"  data-modal-title="Купить в 1 клик" data-modal-subtitle="Мы перезвоним вам в ближайшее время" rel="nofollow">Выбрать</a>
```

Сама форма:

```
            <form action="telegram.php" method="POST" class="" novalidate="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="form-label">Имя</p>
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="billing_first_name" placeholder="Имя Фамилия" autocomplete="first_name" required/="">
                        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Заполните поле</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="form-label">Телефон</p>
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="billing_phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" autocomplete="phone" required/="">
                        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Заполните поле</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   
                        
                        
                  
                </div>
                 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="product" value="Товар0">  
                <button class="btn btn-black">Отправить</button>
                                          
                </form>
```

Я хочу, чтобы значение дата-атрибута передавалось в `<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="product" value="Товар0">`

Нашел такой код, но он не работает почему-то

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('a.add_to_cart_button').addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
  let inputText = document.querySelector('form input[type="hidden"]');
  inputText.value = event.target.dataset.product;
  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue=false);
}, false);


  </script>
```

Comment: а что именно в скрипте не работает? Вы смотрели каждый шаг?

Comment: Значение из дата-атрибута в input не передаётся

Comment: а что значит вот это `event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue=false);` ?

Comment: А вот этого не знаю, я готовый скрипт вставил и просто заменил классы

Comment: А с чего ты взял что не передаётся? На основе каких выводов?

Comment: Код работает вполне себе

Comment: Может у вас проблемы с совместимостью? Попробуйте заменить `dataset` на `getAttribute()`

Comment: Вот так?
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('a.add_to_cart_button').addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
  let inputText = document.querySelector('form input[type="hidden"]');
  inputText.value = getAttribute('product');
 
}, false);


  </script>

Comment: `inputText.value = event.target.getAttribute('data-product');`